# Windows service is not working after oracle db dll changes?

Tags: service, window

Windows service is not working after oracle db dll changes.

- I have tried to change permission of windows and users

Comment: Create new exe file and try again It worked for me. Some time db driver can cause the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create new exe file and try again It worked for me. Some time db driver can cause the issue.

- Change permission of word, excel interop dll,
- try to redeploy dll
- try to clean and rebuild